# Multiple EntityManagerFactory with multiple datasources AND different packagesToScan

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Been trying to find a solution for this but unable to get any to work.

I have two `entityManagerFac` beans defined in the `root-context.xml` and have no `persistence.xml` defined:

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFac" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" autowire="byName">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="entityManagerFactory1" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>my.common</value>
                <value>my.biz</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
<!--                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop> -->
                    <prop key="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                    <prop key="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFac2"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" autowire="byName">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds2" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="entityManagerFactory2" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>my.new</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
<!--                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop> -->
                    <prop key="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                    <prop key="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

As in the settings, the packages `my.common` and `my.biz` need to use `datasource1` while `my.new` would need to use `datasource2`.

However when I try to run this, I got the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type:
```

for one of the models.

Understand that this could caused by the model not being scanned with the `persistenceUnitName` there. Is there anyway to overcome this without the introduction of a persistence.xml?

**EDIT**
Adding the `jpa:repositories` settings:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="my.repository.common" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFac"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="my.repository.biz" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFac"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="my.repository.new" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFac2"/>
```

Comment: `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`s need to be associated with specific repositories to work. Since there are two instances of this class in the configuration, there need to be two separate `<jpa:repositories />` configurations as well, each pointing to a single `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. See [my sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-data-jta/blob/master/src/main/resources/springContext.xml) for reference.

Comment: @manish yes i do have separate repo setting. Had updated my question with them.

Comment: The first two `<jpa:repositories />` declarations can be combined into one by separating the package names with a comma. Other than that, I am not getting any errors with your configuration. See [this sample](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/48396867). Your logs should show which entity is complained about in the message `Not a managed type`.

Comment: Managed to find the root cause. It is caused by 1 of the entity class not having the correct @Entity annotation :S . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause found: There is a entity class that was supposed to be annotated with the `@Entity` annotation was not included correctly in the build.

Once that is rectify the setting worked as expected.